# I have Catalina installed as a dual-boot on a Mojave box. Catalina never got past basic installation, and is a basket case. How can I salvage it?

Tags: catalina, partition

Two years ago, rather than updating my 2017 iMac directly from Mojave to Catalina (and risk the possibility of breaking something mission-critical), I split the hard drive, and scratch-installed Catalina on the new partition, with the goal of eventually removing the Mojave partition once I got everything running on the Catalina partition.

That didn't go well on the Catalina side: it never got past basic OS installation (too many applications didn't work), and the attempt was abandoned.

I now need to salvage this, in order to use applications that require Catalina or better.

There is, fortunately, very little on the Catalina partition that's worth saving, and so I can wipe it clean and start from scratch.

Would it be practical, once the partition has been wiped clean, to clone the Mojave partition into it, and then update the clone to Catalina (or Big Sur, or Monterey)?

Comment: Do you still have *"the goal of eventually removing the Mojave partition once I got everything running on the Catalina partition"*? If the answer is "Yes", then what do you intend to do with the free space created by the removed Mojave partition?

Comment: As best I can determine from your current question, the answer would be the following. It would ***not*** be practical, once the partition has been wiped clean, to clone the Mojave partition into it, and then update the clone to Catalina (or Big Sur, or Monterey). It would be practical, once the partition has been wiped clean, to clone the Mojave partition into it, and then update the ***original*** to Catalina (or Big Sur, or Monterey).

Comment: Any particular reason for updating the original, rather than the clone? Ease of removing the Mojave partition and recovering the space?

Comment: Yes: *"Ease of removing the Mojave partition and recovering the space"*. Here I assume the Mojave partition is above the Catalina partition. If you remove the Mojave partition, you can not simply add the free space to the other partition, because the free space will be above the other partition.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense.